# Add "Hot Questions" link in stackexchange.com navigation tabs

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, stackexchange.com, hot-questions

I reached [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions) list on stackexchange.com and wanted to move to the Hot Questions page. I looked around for Hot Questions link and didn't find any.

The one and only way to see the Hot Network Questions list is to go to stackexchange.com **homepage**. The list does not even have its own URL.

This is very counterintuitive and confusing.

Can there please be a clear link to the Hot Network Questions list, e.g. like this?

> [image]